# My code won't take me to the next screen

Tags: java, android, mobile

I want to click on the list view item and go to the next screen but it won't let me click on the list view. I been following this guy on Youtube his one work and I have double checked my code but my one doesn't seem to work.

Link for the video I Followed:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mm6k1KAGFgA&index=2&list=PLk7v1Z2rk4hj6SDHf_YybDeVhUT9MXaj1

If someone could help me would be Great!!!

my code:

```
   listViewStudents.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Student student = students.get(i);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddStudentGradeActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra(STUDENT_ID, student.getStudentName());
                intent.putExtra(STUDENT_NAME, student.getStudentName());

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: How would some know error, if you don't post stacktrace?

Comment: are you inside of an activity for a fragment at this point? my guess is it fails on the Student student line.

Comment: the error doesn't show in the android studios cause the code is fine but it won't take me to the next screen.

Comment: Could you set a log before your Intent, to be sure your listener works well?

Comment: check to see if the `setOnItemClickListener` is being triggered by adding a `Log.e(TAG, "setOnItemClickListener -- click")`

Comment: does your app crash and show a process stopped? if so, there IS  a log. click on logcat at the bottom of android studio

Comment: the following show on the logcat

Comment: "Inactivity, disconnecting from the service"

Comment: Also check activity is defined in manifest.

Comment: can you remove the everything under the Student student = students.get(i); code and put in a toast instead? when u click on the row, does the toast show?

Comment: also, what is in students? That looks like its a list... you are doing students.get(i) which would be the index of the row clicked, yes? is 'students' creating the adapterview?

Comment: you would probably want to do intent.putExtra(STUDENT_ID, students.get(i).getStudentName()); instead of what you have... hard to tell because im not seeing the entire file

Comment: public static final String STUDENT_NAME = "studentname";
    public static final String STUDENT_ID  = "studentid";

    EditText editTextStudentName, editTextacademicyear, editTextTypeCourse;
    Button buttonAddStudent;

    DatabaseReference databaseReferenceStudents;

    ListView listViewStudents;

    List<Student> students;

Comment: @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_main);

        databaseReferenceStudents = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("students");

        editTextStudentName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStudentName);
        editTextacademicyear = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextacademicyear);
        editTextTypeCourse = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTypeCourse);
        buttonAddStudent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddStudent);

Comment: listViewStudents = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewStudents);

        students = new ArrayList<>();
        buttonAddStudent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                addStudent();
            }
        });

Comment: listViewStudents.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                Student student = students.get(i);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddStudentGradeActivity.class);

                intent.putExtra(STUDENT_ID, student.getStudentName());
                intent.putExtra(STUDENT_NAME, student.getStudentName());

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

Comment: u need to edit your original question and post ALL of your code at this point. very hard to follow from comments

Comment: post code and manifest

Answer (score 0):

- Check if `onItemClickListener` is called;
- Check if `AddStudentGradeActivity` is defined in manifest.
- Replace `getApplicationContext()` with activity context. If your enclosing class is activity just use `<YourActivity>.this`, if it is fragment use `<YourFragment>.this.getContext()`, so you get

`Intent intent = new Intent(<YourActivity>.this, AddStudentGradeActivity.class);`

or
`Intent intent = new Intent(<YourFragment>.this.getContext(), AddStudentGradeActivity.class);`

Comment: what you mean by Fragment?